# Jenkins installation on tomcat giving hudson.util.NoTempDir: java.io.IOException: No such file or directory

Tags: tomcat, jenkins

Deployed Jenkins on tomcat failed with the following error in the logs.

```
 SEVERE: Failed to initialize Jenkins
    hudson.util.NoTempDir: java.io.IOException: No such file or directory
        at hudson.WebAppMain.contextInitialized(WebAppMain.java:201)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5099)
        at .........
```

Comment: To check if the folder `temp` exist in the home path of tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

This happened because jenkins was looking for temp folder in tomcat root directory to start.

Creating the folder set in CATALINA_TMPDIR environment variable, which by default is set to 'temp' in tomcat root folder with write permissions helped the deployment to go through.